# Express: How does next() work with multiple Route handlers?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Express and I'm confused about how `next()` work in this situation:

```
//Route 1
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('ID:', req.params.id)
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('User Info')
})

// Route 2
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.end(req.params.id)
})
```

In the above example, what is the sequence of execution? Theoretically, Is `res.end(req.params.id)` executed earlier than `res.send('User Info')`? (Even though the res.end() will end the request-response cycle.)
What does the `next()` do in this situation?

Or consider another situation :

```
//Route 1
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('1')
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('2')
})

// Route 2
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('3')
})
```

What sequence gets printed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Express middleware are functions that execute during the lifecycle of a request to the Express server. Each middleware has access to the HTTP request and response for each route (or path) it's attached to. In fact, Express itself is compromised wholly of middleware functions.

The middleware function has 2/3/4 parameters based on its usage which looks something like this:

```
function (error, request, response, next) {}
```

When the router gets active express will start executing from the first middleware, and next is used to pass the execution to the subsequent middleware in the list.

```
app.get('path', 'middleware 1', 'middleware 2', 'middleware 3', ... so on)
```

The case you want to understand:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('1')
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('2')
})

// Route 2
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('3')
})
```

Your routes are the same, express will always execute the first matching route and `route 1` will be executed which uses next to pass the execution to next middleware. The o/p will always be :

```
1
2
```

> In the above example, what is the sequence of execution?
> Theoretically, Is res.end(req.params.id) executed earlier than
> res.send('User Info')? (Even though the res.end() will end the
> request-response cycle.) What does the next() do in this situation?

Route1 will be executed and once you are sending the response, express internally calls the next to pack the response and send it.

The `next` function is a function in the Express router which, when invoked, executes the middleware succeeding the current middleware.